# Javascript in partial (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For example i have many comments rendered for the post.

```
<%= render post.comments %>
```

And in comments partial i have javascript wich will repeated so many times how many comments i have

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div id="content_<%= comment.id %>"><%= comment.content %></div>
<scr​ipt>$("content_<%= comment.id %>").click(function() { a​lert(​'content of comment <%= comment.id %>'​) });</sc​ript>
```

What is the best way to avoid repeating javascript in source code?
I tried to create *_comment.js.erb* file and put javascript there, but i don't understand how to make it work.

Can anyone please explain me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the implementation to have a single js file under app/assets/javascripts with your script inside. change the selector of the script to match the class of the comments instead of a unique ID. If required, use javascript to read the content of elements, instead of doing this on the server as you do now.

Comment: But if i will have script in assets/javascripts how can i tell rails that each comment have his own script? Thats why i'm using content_<%= comment.id %>

Comment: You're right. The idea is to have the same script for all, and differentiate between the comments in the script code itself. I assume this is the same logic for all the comments, only with different data.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but can you please explain more?

Comment: in your selector, use class, instead of id (something like: $('.comment')). in the alert, use $(this).attr("id"), or something similar with another attribute in order to fetch the actual data. The code should be roughly something like this: $('.comment').click(function() { a​lert($(this).attr("id")​) });